# Using global variables in static voids - C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, static

I'm writing a very basic C# program which works with lists.

I'm writing a method which sorts a list into order and then writes the result out to a text box using a global variable.

I want to method to be a static void however this throws errors.

Currently it looks like this:

```
public void sort(List<int> value) 
{
    value.Sort();
    foreach (int item in value)
    {
        result = result + item;
    }
}
```

I want this to however be a static void as follows:

```
public static void sort(List<double> value)
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: You can either make `result` static or make it a parameter of the method. Additionally, you can do `value.Sum()` to achieve what you're doing.

Comment: Why must you use a global variable? What's wrong with making `result` local and returning it from `sort`? Doing this will also give you an opportunity to change `sort` to a name that says what it actually does.

Comment: I have been given the public static void sort(List<double> value) line so it needs to follow this format.

Comment: Seems like your `sort` method is doing more than just sorting.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a global variable inside of a method is not a good practice and is advisable to avoid unless absolutely necessary. If you were to transport this method to another module it would stop working if you use any global variable.

Looking at your method, what it does is simply sort a list and add up the values. So do something like this:

```
public static int sort(List<int> value) 
{
    int result;
    value.Sort();
    foreach (int item in value)
    {
        result = result + item;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using `LINQ`;

```
public static int sort(List<int> value)
{
    value.Sort();
    return value.Sum();
}
```

If the return type 'MUST' be `void`, use an `out` parameter.

```
public static void sort(List<int> value, out int result)
{
    value.Sort();
    result = value.Sum();
}
```